# Is there any contraindication for using the same servers for shards and config?

Tags: mongodb

I'm wondering if there's any contraindication for installing on the same server a config instance and a shard instance. for instance we have two shards with 3 replicas each (6 servers), and each one has a config server instance too for the same config replica.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A need for PCI compliance would be a contraindication. PCI DSS version 3.2 requires that you "Implement only one primary function per server to prevent functions that require different security levels from co-existing on the same server". Config and sharding would be two primary functions.